# Advanced search not working properly on partition

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

This applies to the partition drive. I am having trouble using the advanced features of Windows search. If I try to search, for example `type:folder`, it won't load anything even though there are folders in that drive. It works in Windows 7 and I dont think I had to do anything. Is there something extra I have to do on 10 to get it working?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove , here is the url [link](http://i20.photobucket.com/albums/b212/kosmos_corn88/issues/folders_search.png) . I'm searching the entire drive which have folders & its not listing them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `kind:folder` instead of `type:folder`.

Comment: that works however, I have other types that I search for occasionally, that is not part of kind, that it won't find. For example, I use `type:server` to search for asp.net server page files, and it doesn't list them even though they are on the drive.